# Accessing parameters sent to the Custom Logger .NETCore 3.1

Tags: .net-core, ilogger

I am trying to implement custom ILogger . NetCore 3.1

CustomLogger class implements the ILogger. one of the methods thats need to be implemented is:

```
 public class AuditLogLogger: ILogger
 {
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
{
   // How can I access the parameters I sent it from the controller?
}
}
```

From My controller I triggered the LogInformation Method and passeed a string,
and a List of KeyValuePair as such:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> udf = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
udf.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Test", "Test"));
_logger.LogInformation("This is a test", udf);
```

My code is able to make it to the Log<TState> but I need to perform some logic based on the parameters passed in. How can I access the parameters passed?

Comment: Not clear what you have problem with. If you are implementing your own CustomLogger, then you could implement your own Log and access parameters there

Comment: @NikitaChayka Thanks for your reply. Yes I implemented my own custom logger. and would need to have acccess to all parameters sent when I trigger one of the log functions. Updated the description. is it more clear now?\

Comment: No, not clear, why wouldn't you implement LogInformation and access parameters from there?

Comment: @NikitaChayka those parameters needs to be passed in to loginformation method

Comment: Yeah, eactly, so why you need them in Log<TState> ? why wouldn't you simply access them in LogInformation and perform your logic

Comment: When I call logger.LogInformation from my controller, my debuggers calls the Log<TState> function.

Comment: So do you actually implement an ILogger interface, or you inherit some existing Logger?

Comment: @NikitaChayka I impleneted ILogger. Updated the description to include additional code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224047/discussion-between-mikey-and-nikita-chayka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a dirty solution
Basically, have my controller send in a json string containing the list and message then have the Log function deserialize it such as

```
string message = "this is a test";
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> udf = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string();
udf.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Test", "Test"));
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj["Message"] = message;
obj["MyList"] = JArray.FromObject(udf);
```

The Log Message needs to deserialize

I am sure there is a cleaner solution